# How to draw vertical lines that one end matchs the curve in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

like in the picture, I want to make one end of the vertical/horizontal lines exactly match the curve. I'm currently using the `plt.axvline` method, but I can't set the `xmax` parameter right. How to achieve this?

Comment: Use [`hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html) and [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html)

Answer (score 2):

`ax.axhline` needs its x-positions as fraction of the width of the subplot.  `ax.hlines` can work with x-positions in data coordinates, and also allows to draw many lines at the same time.

`np.interp()` can calculate the heights under the curve. When working with timestamps, they need to be converted to datetime format when used in numpy functions.

Here is some example code to get you started:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# define a time range for the x-axis
time_range = pd.date_range('20210101 08:00:00', freq='10s', periods=600)
# calculate some random data for the y-axis
y = (np.random.rand(600) ** 4).cumsum()

# plot the curve
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 5))
ax.plot(time_range, y, color='skyblue')
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax.set_xlim(xmin=time_range[0])

# format the x-axis as HH:MM:SS
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

# have a list of special time stamps
special_timestamps = np.random.choice(time_range, 20)

# mark the positions of the special time stamps in the x-axis
ax.set_xticks(special_timestamps)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

# calculate the height of each of the special time stamps to reach the curve
heights = np.interp(pd.to_datetime(special_timestamps), pd.to_datetime(time_range), y)
# draw the vertical lines
ax.vlines(special_timestamps, 0, heights, color='red', ls='--')

# draw the horizontal lines
ax.hlines(heights, time_range[0], special_timestamps, color='red', ls='--')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: lines up to a curve, timestamps as x-axis]